# Numpy: Broadcast single element to len n array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a dataframe.

This dataframe has string content.  I need do the following:

```
for i in range(0,100000):
   label = raw.values[i,3]
   stackable = np.asarray([label for i in range(40)]).reshape((-1,1))
   data.append(np.hstack(some_other_data,stackable))
```

This is a small example of what I am trying to do, and it is taking a very long time in python. What is the "proper" way to do this using numpy?

Comment: Is `some_other_data` of constant size? Also, what type is `data`?

Comment: Is `label` a fixed-length string? Maybe you could add 3 lines at the top to generate synthetic data please?

Comment: That list comprehension repeats `label` 40 times.  why?

Comment: `stackable=np.full(40, label)`.  You might want to add a string dtype that's as long your longest label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`full` should be a fast(er) way of 'replicating' a string in an array:

```
In [84]: np.full(4, 'label')                                                                     
Out[84]: array(['label', 'label', 'label', 'label'], dtype='<U5')
In [85]: alist = []                                                                              
In [86]: labels = ['one','two','three']                                                          
In [87]: for i in range(3): 
    ...:     temp=np.full(3,labels[i]) 
    ...:     alist.append(temp) 
    ...:                                                                                         
In [88]: alist                                                                                   
Out[88]: 
[array(['one', 'one', 'one'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['two', 'two', 'two'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['three', 'three', 'three'], dtype='<U5')]
In [89]: np.array(alist)                                                                         
Out[89]: 
array([['one', 'one', 'one'],
       ['two', 'two', 'two'],
       ['three', 'three', 'three']], dtype='<U5')
```

or with a list comprehension:

```
In [91]: np.array([np.full(3,l,'U7') for l in labels])                                           
Out[91]: 
array([['one', 'one', 'one'],
       ['two', 'two', 'two'],
       ['three', 'three', 'three']], dtype='<U7')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

`stackable = np.asarray([label for i in range(40)]).reshape((-1,1))`

with

`stackable = np.asarray([label]*40).reshape((-1,1))`

gets a 10-20% performance improvement on my machine. There may be more that can be done, but it's hard to say without knowing a little more about `data` and `some_other_data`.